# Show instance for a type

Tags: haskell, instance, show

I have those types in my program :

```
type Store = [(String, Float)]
type Handler = [String] -> Store -> IO (Store)

data Command = Command {
    name :: String,        -- Nom de la commande
    description :: String, -- Description de la commande
    exits :: Bool,         -- Drapeau pour sortir de la boucle 
                           -- Vrai pour quit, faux pour les autres
    run :: Handler         -- Le code à executer             
}
```

I want to create two instance for `Show Handler` and `Show Store` but I don't know the right syntax of `Show Instance` for types.

Comment: But `Handler` is a function. How can you `Show` a function? You also defined type aliasses, instead of new types.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show handlers, I suggest bundling a name with the handler:

```
data Handler = Handler String ([String] -> Store -> IO Store)
```

Then when you create a handler you give it a name:

```
myHandler :: Handler
myHandler = Handler "my handler" $ \args store -> do
    ...
```

and you can use the name to show the handler:

```
instance Show Handler where
    show (Handler name _) = "<handler " ++ show name ++ ">"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't usefully define `Show Handler` because it's a function type.  You have no way to break a function value down and show anything useful.

You don't need to define `Show Store` because it's already defined, based on `instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a,b)` and `instance Show a => Show [a]` from the Prelude.